# Zend_Controller_Router_Route issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, zend-route

I need to trim the first part of my url

Example `/param1/12234/module/controller/action`
would become `/module/controller/action/param1/12234`

I tried with

> $router->addRoute('appid', new
>   Zend_Controller_Router_Route('appid/:appid/:module/:controller/:action/',
>   array(), array(2=> "module", 3=> "controller", 4=> "action")));

but won't works!

some helps?

Comment: Hi, just following up to see if the RewriteRule I provided in my update helped at all. Best

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php

   //-------------------------
   // Get router from front
   // controller
   $router = $this->frontController->getRouter();

   //-------------------------
   // Create route
   $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
      'controller/action/:appid/:param1',
      array(
         'module' => default',
         'controller' => 'index',
         'action' => 'index',
         'appid' => '',
         'param1' => 'default_value'
      ),

      //-------------------------
      // You can even add a regex
      // to parameters. Example,
      // appid can only be an integer
      array(
         'appid' => '\d+'
      )
   );

   //-------------------------
   // Add route to Router
   $router->addRoute('appid', $route);
?>
```

Of'course, you'll need to substitute a few things (module, controller, action and parameters).  If you're not using modules, simply delete it from the array.

Finally, to use the route in the view, you can use:

```
$this->url(array('appid' => 1, 'param1' => 'custom_value'),'appid');
```

### UPDATE:

You can try the following in your

```
<VirtualHost>

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^/appid/(.*) /module/controller/action/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

If you don't need to use a permanent 301 redirect, you can drop the R

Comment: the basic are that I need to use this url http://www.example.com/appid/1234567 as my base url (facebook related problem) and append module/controller/actio and parameters. I need to cut off the appid/1234567 part BEFORE the default routing. A mod_rewrite solution would be accepted :D

Comment: Thanks for the additional info Antonello. I added an update. Please let me know if that helps. Best

Comment: NOTE: You'll still want to have a good route set up in order to have your app work as expected. Best

Comment: tkz for the suggestion. I'll try RewriteRule ^/appid/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /$2/$3/$4/appid/$1/$5{%QUERYSTRING} [R=301,L]